# How to run Applescript via bash from JAMF?

Tags: macos, applescript, bash, mdm

this apple script code works fine from the Script Editor app:

```
tell application "Finder" to delete ((POSIX file "/Applications/Symantec Solutions/Symantec Endpoint Protection.app") as alias)
```

Now, I need to run that from my MDM solution (JAMF), so I'm trying to get it into a bash file as this:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to delete (POSIX file \"/Applications/Symantec Solutions/Symantec Endpoint Protection.app\") as alias"
```

but when run it from my editor (CodeRunner) it fails with: **execution error: Not authorised to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)**

I think it's related with the Privacy Preferences Policy Control but I cannot make it work.

What I want to accomplish ultimately is that by running a script from my MDM I can get the same dialog that when I drag de app to the bin: **"The application “Symantec Endpoint Protection” is hosting system extensions. These extensions will be removed if you continue."** which I don't get if I just `rm -rf` the whole app.

Sorry if I can't be any clearer. Any clues?

Comment: Same identical issue here, my script is identical to yours except that I split every line in a new `-e "xxxx"`.
If I run the script locally or in a bash script all works and I see the alert, if I run the script via SSH I see "26:34: execution error: Finder got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)"

Comment: Hi Kappe, I ended up replacing "System Events" with "Finder", which was already whitelisted in PPPC.